# Time limit exceeded when list with large number of elements used?

Tags: c#

Function fails performance test when run with a large number of elements: Time limit exceeded .
    How to pass Performance Test ?

```
 //Function finds indices of two elements whose sum is equal to as passed in the parameter
 public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
     {
         int sum2 = sum - list[i];
         int index = list.IndexOf(sum2);
         if (index > 0 )
         {
             return new Tuple<int, int>(i, index);
         }
     }
     return null;
 }

 //Main function to call FindTwoSum method
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
  Tuple<int, int> indices = FindTwoSum(new List<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 },12);
  Console.WriteLine(indices.Item1 + " " + indices.Item2);
 }
```

Comment: All pairs or any pair?

Comment: If you use an array instead of a list it will be faster. Also, does this give the right answer for, say: `100, 100, 5, 100, 100` with a target sum of `10`? It will give the same index twice for that.

Comment: I notice that your input array in your example is sorted. Is this true for every case?

Comment: @Carlos : Question is about finding any pair and thanks for suggesting the approach about reducing the complexity of alogorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carlos is right when saying that complexity can be greatly reduced to O(n), when using hash sets. The code should look like this:

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSumFaster(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    if (list == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("Null list");

    // constructing a hashset to have O(1) operations
    var listSet = new HashSet<int>();

    // number -> index mapping
    // O(n) complexity
    var listReverseSet = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var elem in list)
    {
        if (!listSet.Contains(elem))
            listSet.Add(elem);

        listReverseSet[elem] = i++;
    }

    // O(n) complexity
    int listCount = list.Count;
    for (int index = 0; index < listCount; index ++)
    {
        var elem = list[index];

        if (listSet.Contains(sum - elem))
            return new Tuple<int, int>(index, listReverseSet[sum - elem]);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and also it clears my concept about time complexity a little bit..i need to practice more questions about algorithmic thinking to make it more clear..Thanks once again!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

It would seem on the face of it that the hashing solution should be the fastest - and indeed, it probably is for really huge arrays that exceed 2GB in size.

However (surprisingly) for `int` arrays up to 50,000,000 elements in size it is faster to sort the array and use an optimised algorithm that works with a sorted array.

Here's an algorithm you can use on a sorted array (note that it requires an extra array which is just used to indicate the original indices of the elements before sorting):

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSumInSortedList(IList<int> list, int[] indices, int sum)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = list.Count - 1; i < j;)
    {
        int s = list[i] + list[j];

        if (s == sum)
            return new Tuple<int, int>(indices[i], indices[j]);
        else if (s < sum)
            ++i;
        else
            --j;
    }

    return null;
}
```

It takes a bit of extra work to sort the original list:

```
int n = 10000000;
int[] array = new int[n];
...
var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, n).ToArray();
Array.Sort(array, indices);
result = FindTwoSumInSortedList(array, indices, target);
```

This does seem like a huge amount of extra work, but to my surprise, it outperforms the hash algorithm on an array of 20,000,000 elements.

I'm posting my test program below, for criticism. I've tried to make the sample data as awkward as possible for the `FindTwoSumInSortedList()` algorithm.

The results I get from a RELEASE build on my PC are:

```
n = 10,000,000 

3031
(5000000, 5000001)
1292
(5000000, 5000001)

n = 20,000,000

6482
(10000000, 10000001)
2592
(10000000, 10000001)

n = 50,000,000

17408
(25000000, 25000001)
5653
(25000000, 25000001)
```

So you can see the algorithm with sorting is more than twice as fast. That really surprised me!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int n = 10000000;
            int[] array = new int[n];
            var rng = new Random(18789);

            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                array[i] = rng.Next(0, n);

            array[n/2] = n;
            array[n/2 + 1] = n+1;

            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            // This is too slow to test:
            //var result = FindTwoSum(array, n*2+1);
            //Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            //Console.WriteLine(result);

            sw.Restart();
            var result = FindTwoSumFaster(array, n*2 + 1);
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            sw.Restart();
            var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, n).ToArray();
            Array.Sort(array, indices);
            result = FindTwoSumInSortedList(array, indices, n*2+1);
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                int sum2 = sum - list[i];
                int index = list.IndexOf(sum2);
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    return new Tuple<int, int>(i, index);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSumInSortedList(IList<int> list, int[] indices, int sum)
        {
            for (int i = 0, j = list.Count - 1; i < j;)
            {
                int s = list[i] + list[j];

                if (s == sum)
                    return new Tuple<int, int>(indices[i], indices[j]);
                else if (s < sum)
                    ++i;
                else
                    --j;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSumFaster(IList<int> list, int sum)
        {
            if (list == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("Null list");

            // constructing a hashset to have O(1) operations
            var listSet = new HashSet<int>();

            // number -> index mapping
            // O(n) complexity
            var listReverseSet = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var elem in list)
            {
                if (!listSet.Contains(elem))
                    listSet.Add(elem);

                listReverseSet[elem] = i++;
            }

            // O(n) complexity
            int listCount = list.Count;
            for (int index = 0; index < listCount; index++)
            {
                var elem = list[index];

                if (listSet.Contains(sum - elem))
                    return new Tuple<int, int>(index, listReverseSet[sum - elem]);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Matt , Thanks for your full analysis for the code . since i practiced the above code using one of the online coding platform and i didn't knew about what approach to take to test performance of the code, your code make that clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your time limit is exceeded probably because you are doing an O(n^2) operation. You can solve it in O(n), and whatever is checking your time probably knows this.

If it's just a matter of finding any pair that has the desired sum, do this:

- For each item, calculate the number required. Eg if sum = 10 and you see 7, you need to store 3. Store it in a hash set, O(1).
- As you go through the list, check for presence in the hash set. Again, O(1).
- So in total you have an O(n) instead of O(n^2) like what you have submitted.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using a similar approach. It is as fast as the other solutions, because it goes through the list only once, considering that the access to the dictionary is O (1) the solution will have complexity of O (n).

You can test the code here: [TESTDOME - Two sum](https://www.testdome.com/questions/35922)

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    if (list == null)
        return null;

    var listSet = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    int i = 0;
    // O(n)
    foreach (var elem in list)
    {
        if (listSet.Count > 0) {
            var search = sum - elem;
            if (listSet.ContainsKey(search)) {
                var index = listSet[search];
                if (i != index) {
                    return new Tuple<int, int>(i, index);
                }
            }
        }
        listSet[elem] = i++;
    }
    return null;
}
```